# Chrome mouse drag and drop on overlapping divs changes cursor to not allowed

Tags: google-chrome, html, overlapping

Chrome will error, ff will not. Here's as simple as I could get it...

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="page">
</div>
<div class="page">
</div>
<style>
.page   {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    height:400;
    width:400;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Click inside the red div, drag to outside of div, repeat, cursor set to not allowed.

I'm trying to create an html book reader, and I want multiple drag-able overlapping divs. Chrome will change the cursor and kill all mousemove events on the divs. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Hey, I figured it out ish, if anyone is stuck on this. Chrome treats freakin everything as selectable text so when I was dragging the mouse, chrome was highlighting the div beneath. If I dragged outside of the area the div beneath was selected but not visibly so, so when I tried dragging again, chrome was trying to move the image, which canceled all other mouse events. Easy work around is

 pointer-events:none;
 user-select: none;
   -o-user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

Comment: Hey thanks for answering your own question. This was really hard to debug! And your answer helped a lot. If you are custom building something that's needs to be draggable its necessary to add your CSS code!